# Can you have multiple get action methods in asp net web api controller according to RESTful API constraints?

Tags: asp.net, rest, api, asp.net-web-api

I have the following interface in my business layer

```
    public interface IUserService
    {
        void CreateUser(User user);
        List<User> FindUsersByName(string searchedString);
        User GetUserById(int userId);
        User GetUserByCredentials(string login, string password);
        void UpdateUser(User user);
        void UpdateUserPassword(int userId, string oldPassword, string newPassword);
    }
```

Now I want to provide web api for this interface. As you can see this interface has multiple `get` methods that return one item `GetUserById` and `GetUserByCredentials`, it also has multiple update methods `UpdateUser` and `UpdateUserPassword`, in future I might want to add aditional get method that returns a collection, like, `GetAllUsers` for instance.

The obvious solution was to encapsulate this functionality in one controller. 
So what I did first, in `WebApiConfig` I changed routes configuration to

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                //as you can see I added {action} to the path so that, it will be possible to differentiate between different get/put requests
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Then I created a `UsersController` that looks like this

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IUserService _userService;

        public UsersController(IUserService userService)
        {
            _userService = userService;
        }

        // POST api/users/createuser
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult CreateUser(User user)
        {
            //some code
        }

        // GET api/users/getuserbyid?id=1
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetUserById(int id)
        {
            //some code
        }

        // GET api/users/getuserbycredentials?login=log&password=pass
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetUserByCredentials(string login, string password)
        {
            //some code
        }


        // GET api/users/findusersbyname?searchedString=jack
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult FindUsersByName(string searchedString)
        {
            //some code
        }

        // PUT api/users/updateuser
        [HttpPut]
        public IHttpActionResult UpdateUser(UserBase user)
        {
            //some code
        }

        // PUT api/users/updateuserpassword?userId=1&oldPassword=123&newPassword=1234
        [HttpPut]
        public IHttpActionResult UpdateUserPassword(int userId, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
        {
            //some code
        }
    }
```

As you can see from the code above I have different URIs for each action method, e.g., for `GetUserById` - `api/users/getuserbyid?id=1`, for `GetUserByCredentials` - `api/users/getuserbycredentials?login=log&password=pass` and so on. This solution works fine so far, but the problem is, as far as I know you cannot have multiple gets according to REST, so does this solution still comply with the constraints for a RESTful service? And if not how can I make it truly RESTful? The idea of splitting this interface into different controllers seems a little odd to me, because in the future I may want to add some new methods to my interface, like, `GetUsersByGender`, `GetUsersByDateOfBirthday` and so on (if I'm going to create a new controller each time, that doesn't sound right to me)